# Transition between two pages doesn't work with vue.js and GSAP

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, gsap

I've started to learn vue.js, and I want to do a transition using GSAP (and not css) between two pages, so I found those properties : `v-on:enter`, `v-on:leave`.

It seems that my `v-on:enter` animation is only working on the first call of my app. I don't see the "leave" animation, plus I have some duplicated content when the new page appears.

I've two questions here :

- What am I missing ?
- How can I start my `v-on:enter` animation when the DOM is fully loaded? (so far my animation starts even if my DOM is not fully loaded)

Here's the code I use on my App.vue file, thank you very much.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <transition 
      appear
      v-on:enter="enter" 
      v-on:leave="leave"
      v-bind:css="false"
    >
      <router-view/>
    </transition>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { TweenMax } from "gsap/TweenMax";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  methods: {
    enter(el, done) {
      TweenMax.to('body', 1, {opacity:1, onComplete:done});
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      TweenMax.to('body', 1, {opacity:0, onComplete:done});
    }   
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `out-in` [transition mode](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) to transition the current view out first, then when complete, the new view transitions in.
2. Create a `beforeEnter` method in your component methods option to set the target element `opacity` to `0`.
3. Listen to the `beforeEnter` [JavaScript hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) by adding `v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"` to the
   `transition` component.

---

Unless there is a good reason to use `body` as your target element, use the view component `el` instead.

---

Revised code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <transition 
      appear
      v-bind:css="false"
      v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
      v-on:enter="enter" 
      v-on:leave="leave"
    >
      <router-view/>
    </transition>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { TweenMax } from "gsap/TweenMax";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  methods: {
    beforeEnter(el) {
      TweenMax.set(el, { opacity: 0 });
    },
    enter(el, done) {
      TweenMax.to(el, 1, { opacity:1, onComplete:done });
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      TweenMax.to(el, 1, { opacity:0, onComplete:done });
    }   
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also I had another issue, leave function didn't work because of the nuxt version I was using. `yarn upgrade nuxt --latest` fixed the whole thing